# Input onChange doesn't fire when deleting sessionStorage values (Next.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm loading data with a custom hook from the session storage into an input, and if I delete the whole field, the onChange() function doesn't trigger. If I only add or delete one character, it works fine, but if I select all (or if the input had only one character), then delete it doesn't seem to do anything.
This only applies, when I delete the content after render, without doing anything else in the input beforehand.

```
//this works fine
const [test, setTest] = useState('test')
<input value={test} onChange={(e) => setTest(e.target.value)} />

//this doesn't trigger, when deleting all content after rendering the default value
const [test2, setTest2] = useSessionStorage({key: 'test2', defaultValue: 'test2'})
<input value={test2} onChange={(e) => setTest2(e.target.value)} />
```

Here is my custom hook:

```
export const useSessionStorage = (hookProps) => {
    const { key, defaultValue } = hookProps

    const [sessionItem, setSessionItem] = useState(() => {
        if (typeof window != 'undefined') {
            const item = sessionStorage.getItem(key)
            return item ? JSON.parse(item) : defaultValue
        }
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        sessionStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(sessionItem))
    }, [key, sessionItem])

    return [sessionItem, setSessionItem]
}
```

I'm sure it has to do something with the session storage loading in the server first, or just after the first render, but I have no solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine. In fact, I did not detect the render when `test` value changes. I added this `useEffect` inside the component,

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("I am rerendering because test value is changing");
  }, [test]);
```

inside `useSessionStorage` useEffect, add this

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("I am rerendering becasue test2 value is changing");

    sessionStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(sessionItem));
  }, [key, sessionItem]);
```

Now test it

Comment: Everything works as intended, except when I delete the content from the second input after loading the page ('test2' to '' with selecting all and pressing delete, or if the value is just 't' then pressing delete). The hook doesn't even get called, since the onChange method for the input doesn't trigger at all. It's like it doesn't even exist until I add or remove a character from that input. After that, it works fine.

Comment: @thepeterkovacs it still works. I could not reproduce the error

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

The session storage loads from the server side, so it gave *undefined* (empty string) at first, and the actual value after. The input got the empty string, and when trying to change it to '', the onChange() didn't trigger, due to no changes.
Writing the input in a component and disabling SSR at import works.

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const DynamicInput = dynamic(() => import('../components/Input'), {
    ssr: false
})

export default function Page(){
    const [test, setTest] = useSessionStorage({ key: 'test', defaultValue: null })

    return (
        <DynamicInput value={test} onChange={(e) => setTest(e.target.value)} />
    )
}
```